# How to top-up an Indian mobile number with a non-Indian bank card?

Tags: india, cellphones, payment-cards, payment, phone-networks

Continuation of: [Is there a possibility to preserve an unused Indian mobile number for a period of time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77151/is-there-a-possibility-to-preserve-an-unused-indian-mobile-number-for-a-period-o/77243#77243)

TLDR: People who travel to India couple of times a year keep one Indian SIM card with them. To keep the same number active, they top-up the number once a year for Rs. 200. Pretty easy to top-up online if you have an Indian bank card. Not easy if you don't. Big websites I've seen (Freecharge, PayTM, etc.) don't take international bank cards.

### Which website to use to top-up an Indian mobile number with a non-Indian bank card?

I don't want to bother my folks in India to do it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oxigen USA website](https://oxigenusa.com/) does the job with EXACT $ to ₹ exchange rate and zero fees. None. Zilch.

Accepted my EU debit card for an Indian mobile phone bill payment.

Small downside: my EU bank fee for converting € to $.
Fee can be avoided if you have a bank account with new age startup banks like [Monzo](https://monzo.com/) (£), [N26](https://n26.com/) (€) or [Revolut](https://revolut.com/) (£/€).

Edit: now that the promotion period is over, the conversation rate is appalling on the website. Also the minimum transaction has to be Rs. 500. Still does the job though.